Installing ICD-API as a Windows service
After installing ICD-Web API as a windows service, downloading the package:
https://icd.who.int/docs/icd-api/ICDAPI-WindowsService/
When configuring the connection through https I get the following error:

The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
Info: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS
endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default
developer certificate could not be found or is out of date. To
generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To
trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs
https --trust'

Is there a way to configure the security certificate through a parameter in the appsettings.json file?
